# Matching words surrounding a particular word - regex

Tags: regex

Say I have these strings:

```
1. TOP FLAT
2. FLAT 7
3. FLAT B
4. GROUND FLOOR FLAT
5. STUDIO 1.02
6. APARTMENT 10
7. GROUND AND FIRST FLOOR MAISONETTE
8. FLAT A
```

What regex expression would give me:

```
1. TOP
2. 7
3. B
4. GROUND FLOOR
5. 1.02 
6. 10
7. Ground and first floor
8. A
```

Case-sensitivity is not important. I've been beating my head against this for the past couple of hours but I can't seem to get anywhere.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: One regex for the whole lot? I'm not clear what logic is being used here.

Comment: If  it can be done with one regex for the whole lot then yeah, but I think I'll have to do it for multiple keywords (flat|apartment|maisonette)

Comment: Why not just search for & delete the words "flat", "apartment", etc.?

Comment: That was my original way of doing it. I thought there might be a smarter way to do things. Maybe I shouldn't try fixing what's not broken

Comment: There's a very real danger of trying to be too clever, and making some code that's unintelligible and inscrutable. Avoid this temptation. Debugging code is twice as hard as writing it, so you need to be half as clever when writing it in the first place ;)

Answer (score 0):

(This is perl, but the RE works)

```
while ( <DATA> ) {
    s/(house|maisonette|studio|apartment|flat) ?//gi; 
    print;
}

 __DATA__
1. TOP FLAT
2. FLAT 7
3. FLAT B
4. GROUND FLOOR FLAT
5. STUDIO 1.02
6. APARTMENT 10
7. GROUND AND FIRST FLOOR MAISONETTE
8. FLAT A
```

Gives:

```
1. TOP 
2. 7
3. B
4. GROUND FLOOR 
5. 1.02
6. 10
7. GROUND AND FIRST FLOOR 
8. A
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[ ]*(?:flat|studio|apartment|Maisonette)[ ]*
```

Try this.Replace by `space`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pM9yO9/10